Facing issue when using onesignal_flutter: ^5.2.2 with Flutter SDK 3.24.0
I found issue when attempting to build my Flutter application in release mode using the onesignal_flutter: ^5.2.2 package. This issue occurs after upgrading to Flutter SDK 3.24.0.
ERROR: ../build/onesignal_flutter/intermediates/merged_res/release/mergeReleaseResources/values/values.xml:2657: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/lStar not found.
I try follow this steps from GitHub repo issues comment:
(https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Flutter-SDK/issues/930#issuecomment-2283832859)

I found this solution in Github repo comments:
Add the code block below to the android/build.gradle file in your project directory.
    allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = "../build"
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    // Add this
    afterEvaluate {
        android {
            compileSdkVersion 34
        }
    }
    // End
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(":app")
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

Solution Link in GitHub

Add this line in your android level build.gradle file
subprojects {

    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"

    // add this line for onesignal_flutter to work in android device
    afterEvaluate {
        android {
            compileSdkVersion 34
        }
    }
}

